# Transacted session with message listener, messages not cosumed

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am using Websphere java classes to implement jms in my application.

Sender code :

```
        MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName(environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_HOSTNAME));
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_PORT)));
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager(environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_QMANAGER));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_CHANNEL));
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
        final String username = environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_USERNAME);
        final String password = environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_PASSWORD);
        MQQueueConnection connection = null;
        if(username != null && username.trim().length() > 0 && password != null && password.trim().length() > 0) {
            connection = (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createQueueConnection(username, password);
        }
        else {
            connection = (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        }
        senderSession = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);            
        MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) senderSession.createQueue("queue:///" + environment.getProperty(MQ_CONNECTION_QUEUE));
        MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) senderSession.createSender(queue);
        JMSMessage message = (JMSMessage)senderSession.createTextMessage(messageContent);
        connection.start();          
        sender.send(message);
        message.acknowledge()
```

Receiver Code :

```
 final MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) (useAuth ? connectionFactory.createQueueConnection(username, password) :      connectionFactory.createQueueConnection());
    connection.start();
    final MQQueueSession receiverSession = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    final MQQueue queue = MQQueue)receiverSession.createQueue(queueName);
    MQQueueReceiver receiver = createReceiver(session, queue);
    receiver.setMessageListener(listener);
```

When I send the message using these settings message listener never receives any message.
But when i open both the sessions with transacted as false, everything seems to work fine.
I can understand the reason.I want to have transactional session.

Let me know in case any other details are required

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a local transaction (syncpoint) then after you send the message you need to commit it.
i.e.

```
senderSession.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

message.Acknowledge() from sender side is not required. It should only be used on the receiver side and in a session with acknowledge type ClientAcknowledge. This call will notify the messaging provider (MQ in this case) to remove the current and all messages received earlier from a queue.